# HAPI 17: Routes not registered

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

Hi I am migrating to Hapi 17 from 16. I have my routes defined in a different file which I am trying to register as a plugin. But I get a 404 when I call the API. The routes are not registered with the server.

This is my Server code.

```js
 'use strict'
    const Hapi = require('hapi')
    const server = new Hapi.Server({ port: 1234, host: 'localhost' });
    const plugins = [{
      plugin: require('vision'),
      plugin: require('./methods/exampleMethod'),
      plugin: require('./routes/devices')
    }]

    async function registerPlugin(){
        await server.register(plugins)
    }
    registerPlugin().then( () => {server.start()})
```

This is my routes file devices.js:

```js
exports.plugin = {
    register: (server, options) =>
    {
        server.routes = [{
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/v1/devices',
            handler: async function (request, h) {
                const val = server.methods.testMethod("ankur")
                const response = h.response('hello world ankur')
                response.type('text/plain')
                return response
            }
          }]
    },
    name: 'devices'
}
```

Methods file

```js
exports.plugin = {
    register: (server, options) => {
        server.method(
          {
            name: 'testMethod',
            method: function (id) {
              return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
              return resolve("Test method called")
              })
            }
          })
    },
    name: "exampleMethod"
```

I am following the release notes for Hapi 17 and trying to register the routes as a custom plugin. However, when I hit the Get v1/devices I get a 404.

Comment: Also, note the plugins object needs muliple objects with 'plugin' property and not one object with same property repeated.

const plugins = [
      { plugin: require('vision') },
      { plugin: require('./methods/exampleMethod') },
      { plugin: require('./routes/devices') }
    }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code for your routes file will work:

```js
 exports.plugin = {
  register: (server, options) => {
    server.route(
      {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/v1/devices",
        handler: async function(request, h) {
          //const val = server.methods.testMethod("ankur")
          const response = h.response("hello world ankur");
          response.type("text/plain");
          return response;
        }
      }
    );
  },
  name: "devices"
};
```

You should call server.route() function with your route object.

If you like to register more than one function through your routes plugin use something like this:

```js
exports.plugin = {
  register: (server, options) => {
    const routes = [
      {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/v1/devices",
        handler: async function(request, h) {
          const response = h.response("hello world");
          response.type("text/plain");
          return response;
        }
      },
      {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/v1/another",
        handler: async function(request, h) {
          const response = h.response("hello another world");
          response.type("text/plain");
          return response;
        }
      }
    ];

    
    server.route(routes);
  
  },
  name: "devices"
};
```

Edit:

Methods plugin

```js
exports.plugin = {
  register: (server, options) => {
    server.method("testMethod", async function(id) {
        return "Test method called";
    });
  },
  name: "exampleMethod"
};
```

Call the method:

```js
{
        method: "GET",
        path: "/v1/example",
        handler: async function(request, h) {
          const response = await request.server.methods.testMethod();

          return response;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @hyde. I was using server.routes. I am facing one more small issue though. I have created a folder methods with another plugin "exampleMethod.js" (Please see edit). And when I call the server.methods.testMethod I get an error "TypeError: server.methods.testMethod is not a function".

Comment: Updated my example for multiple routes, you can call the route method with the array without looping.

Comment: @AnkurBhatia I updated my answer for your methods question.

Comment: I tried the server.methods example. But it says server.methods.testMethod is not a function. I also tried to call with request.server.methods, but getting the same error. @hyde